# How to enable disabled left Alt modifier on spanish keyboard/layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I broke something and I don't really know how to fix it.

I use an spanish keyboard, on an spanish windows 10, with spanish layout and... well, you get the picture, everything is spanish.

For years I've been using Left Alt for several stuff like:

```
Left Alt + `: [  
Left Alt + ´: {  
Left Alt + 3: #  
Left Alt + 2: @
```

However, now, I was programming 1 hour ago and somehow I disabled it. It won't work anymore. `Left Ctrl + Left Alt + something` works exactly as `Left alt + something` should work, so that points out that it's not the phisical key doing something weird, it has to do with software. I uninstalled and re-installed the driver, I closed all programs, I restarted the computer and it still won't work.

For context: I was programming on Pycharm about [Qt Keysequences](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html) so maybe that's why it got broken. Nevertheless, I have no clue why it broke or how to actually fix it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: As said, yes, I restarted the computer.

Comment: I think Qt has its own mechanism. If the previous keys mapping was through the Windows registry (meaning available everywhere), you can remake it via a utility such as [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys).

Comment: I am checking that, what should I do, re-map `Left alt` to `Left alt`? Seems really silly if it really works as the "key where you map" and "key to be mapped" will be the same, because right now Alt key works on stuff like ctrl + alt + something, but alt alone doesn't, like it misses a modifier.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Oh, I will do that then, my apologies. But I don't know if it will let me accept the answer as the site created a new username instead of getting my SO user.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I had a brainfart where I though I used left alt for those things the past 20 years, but I was always using right Alt. My brain trolled me for 3 hours.

If you are here for something similar, think about it for a second.